# How to return a variable in a void

Tags: c#, file, void

I have the following code:

```
static void Scan(string path)
    {
        try{
               foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "zfsdfsdfsb.txt")){
                  Console.WriteLine("FILE: " + file);   
               }

              foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)){
                  Console.WriteLine("DIRECTORY: " + dir);
                  Scan(dir);
               }
           }
    }
```

And i want to stop the function and acess  the variable as soon as

```
Console.WriteLine("FILE: " + file);
```

has been triggered.

I tried to return it, but it diddnt do anything, how can i set a variable and stop the function as soon as the file has been found?

Comment: hard to know what yo mean. Why not post what you tried and maybe we will get a clue about what you are trying to do

Comment: *but it diddnt do anything* - I am sure it did *something*.

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes?

Comment: your code reads like you are actually trying to see if a given file in a given directory exists. Is that right?

Comment: If you want to return a value, then change the return type from void to whatever type the method is supposed to return.

Comment: if i add an return to this, i get the error that i will never reach the return point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `void` to `string`
`static string Scan(string path)`.

Then, inside your loop, return the string when found:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "zfsdfsdfsb.txt")){
     Console.WriteLine("FILE: " + file);   
     return file;
}
```

You'll also need to return a string at the end of the method if nothing was found.

Comment: Maybe he should return `IEnumerable<string>` and do a `yield return file` instead, if he wants to return multiple files. Otherwise, if you want to return just one file, this solution works.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really sure what he really wants and didn't have time to dig into it.  I just wanted to solve his two main problems: Get a value in return; and Stop processing after writing to console.

Comment: also the recursive call to scan needs adjustment

Comment: i actually only want to return only one file

Answer (score -1):

if you are recursively looking for a file that matches a given pattern

```
static string Scan(string path)
    {
        try{
               foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "zfsdfsdfsb.txt")){
                  Console.WriteLine("FILE: " + file);   
                  return file;
               }

              foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)){
                  Console.WriteLine("DIRECTORY: " + dir);
                  var ret = Scan(dir);
                  if(ret != null)
                      return ret;
               }
           }
         return null;
    }
```

if you are looking for a specific file replace first loop with

```
 var fpath = Path.Combine(path,"zfsdfsdfsb.txt");
   if (File.Exists(fpath))
         return fpath;
```